# How to find out the service name, that is required for a SRV record?

Tags: dns, port-forwarding

Im pretty new to Linux so here is my question: Is there any command or any other way (exept googling) to find out the service name that is required for a SRV record (port forwarding? I am using a musicbot for Teamspeak3 (Sinusbot) and i want to access the bot via bot.mydomain.com. The usual way to access it is mydomain.com:8087. I wasn't able to find the service name for it. (In case you don't know what i mean: i need something similar to '_ts3', '_minecraft' and so on but i have to find it out via a command if that's possible)

Comment: If you don't want to use Google, then click on [this direct link](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml) which takes you to the IANA Unified Service Name and Port Registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS SRV record is a way publish a defined service endpoint. Clients can locate the service by retrieving the defined DNS label.

The key here is 'defined', as in registered or at least commonly known among users and providers of the service. I expect determining the name of the process running the service is irrelevant. Knowing what port it is listening on would be relevant and can be found using the `lsof` reference nick064 offered in the comments. More common when determining a listening port on Linux is `netstat -ltunp | grep ${processname}` or `ss -ltunp | grep ${processname}`. (where ${processname} is the actual name you are interested in)

There is no requirement that the name of the application or program running the service be the same thing as the published service label. Many different programs could provide that same service in different environments, and would be associated with the same service name, in the DNS label sense.

DNS SRV records would be largely useless if each operator chose a different label for the same service, as clients would not know what to look up in the DNS.

As gareth commented, IANA maintains a list of registered services (in the Internet sense) -- some of those have associated DNS SRV labels defined. That list is a convenient map of common services to their IETF RFCs. Teamspeak is not on that list, which means you'll need to consult the community of users of the service you are using to learn what the DNS label should be.

[RFC 3263, Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3263#page-8) might be useful to consult for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out all services using:

`service --status-all`

You can parse this through grep to search within the list presented:

`service --status-all | grep pattern`

It may turn out you need to find a certain process, in that case:

`ps aux | grep pattern`

So for example, run `ps aux | grep "_ts3"`

Comment: I think you haven't understood what i need. If you want to forward a port in your DNS management you have to make a SRV record. There you have to write your service name (similar to '_ts3', '_minecraft'). I need to find the service name for the musicbot (something like '_bot', idk what the name is and that's the problem)

Comment: I don't think you understand what a service is. If it is running on your own box, this is how you find it. You can also check /etc/init.d for the startup script on the service you're searching for. 

I also recommend you try: 

`netstat -npl`

This will show you which service is running on which port, along with the name of the service itself and its PID.

Comment: I dont know what's the "translation" for the service that i mean... In the SRV record you have to enter a service name... if i execute the command netstat -npl it shows me all services running.. okay.. but it shows the "real" service name.. For "'code'_ts3" it's "ts3server_linux_[and so on]" http://i.imgur.com/P6XGDYg.png for "_minecraft" it is "minecraft_server.jar" but it doesn't show the "_*" anywhere. For my musicbot it just says "ts3bot" but not the service name, that i need for the SRV record. :/

Comment: Well, lets take an example SRV record and break it down. Their syntax is as follows:

service._proto.name. TTL class SRV priority weight port target.

Practically that would look something like:

 _sip._tcp.example.com. 86400 IN SRV 0 5 5060 sipserver.example.com.

So, for example, try the following for your record: 

_ts3._udp.yourdomain.com 86400 IN SRV 0 5 9987 ts3.yourdomain.com. 

Can you provide the full output for netstat -npl here? Make sure your terminal is maximized, the name is pruned in your last screenshot.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/3IPgPlz.png even when my terminal is maximized, it's cut... My problem isn't really making the SRV record, well it is kind of, but i just need the service name e.g. `_musicbot`

Comment: Try 

lsof | grep -i "ts3"

That should show you all of the services that contain that string, with their full name. Don't be put off if it turns out to be a long SRV record that you have to setup.